# EclipseLink DDL Generation ERROR

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I cannot generate DDL by using `EclipseLink`, when an `Embeddable` class have another `Entity` O/R mapping annotation.
How can I generate DDL for my O/R mapping?

Company.java

```
@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable {
    .....

    @Embedded
    private CompanyAddress address;
}
```

CompanyAddress.java

```
@Embeddable
public class CompanyAddress implements Serializable {
    .....

    @Embedded
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TOWNSHIP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Township township;
}
```

Township.java

```
@Entity
public class Township implements Serializable {
    .....
}
```

When I generate I get the following error,

```
Exception [EclipseLink-195] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The shared class org.ace.insurance.system.common.company.CompanyAddress must not reference the isolated class org.ace.insurance.system.common.township.Townsh
ip.
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[township]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(org.ace.insurance.system.common.company.CompanyAddress --> [DatabaseTable(COMPANY)])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want Township to be a normal seperate entity. In that case you should remove the @Embedded annotation from the township field in CompanyAddress. If you want it to be embedded then Township will need an @Embeddable annotation instead of @Entity.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think, JPA Specification allow `Embedded` class to do O/R Mapping with other `Entity`.